# SharePoint 2007 - False task assignment e-mails

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

I am experiencing a problem with the workflow that is currently being used to manage review tasks on some document. Once the workflow starts, false task assignment e-mails are sent to the requester (i.e. the document owner).

To make the problem clearer let me give an example. Suppose that I am the document owner who will ask people to review my document. When I upload the document to the SharePoint site, e-mail notification is sent to me stating that "Task for A* (person who I am asking to review the document ) assigned to you. This task is assigned to you because person A does not have access to ***_*__** -SharePoint Site."

Actually, Person A does have access to that site.

What could be the reason for such problem?